# Listen to Angular ready from vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to add JS on website made with Angular where I can't edit any existing file, only add new ones. I need to plug my JS and have it running when the website is ready; problem is I don't know when that would be.

Is it possible to know when an Angular app or components of this app have been loaded from outside the very app with vanilla JS?
Kind of `ng.onReady = () => {…}`.

Comment: Not really. But you could test for the existence of a certain element inside your app using a MutationObserver?

Comment: That's a way to do it, thanks for the idea. I was hoping for a built-in angular way to do it, but I guess that'll be enough.

Comment: Cool. I don't think there is a foolproof built-in way to detect this unfortunately.

Comment: Still curious if anyone has a lead though :)

Comment: How 'ready' does the app have to be? There could be lazy loaded modules and/or async calls etc etc. That makes it pretty though I guess? So if there is a specific condition inside your angular app that needs to be done, you could also simply - at that time - trigger a custom event on window - which your script can listen to...

Comment: Just the actual domready version, where all components are written but if there is still some loading for ajax/whatsoever, I don't really care. But as I said, no way to write anything in the existing project, so no custom events that I could trigger from within the app.

Comment: Ah right sorry - I missed that indeed. In that case I would probably go for the MutationObserver route..